# Connect to Columnar Database Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, batch-file

SQL Server 2012 introduces a new index type called a column store index and new query operators that efficiently process batches of rows at a time. These two features together greatly improve the performance of typical data warehouse queries, in some cases by two orders of magnitude. This paper outlines the design of column store indexes and batch-mode processing and summarizes the key beneﬁts this technology provides to customers. It also highlights some early customer experiences and feedback and brieﬂy discusses future enhancements for column store indexes.

My Question is:

**Is there any way to connect PHP-Mysql demo to that type of db?**

There is lot of engines "MySql Based" as follows

- InfiniDB
- Infobright
- MonetDB
- ... etc

Is there any simple getting started with PHP-Mysql?

Comment: are you looking for a column store database that you can connect to with php ? it this your question ?

Comment: not sure i understand your answer

Comment: yes I am looking for a column store database that you can connect to with php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InfiniDB is a GPLv2 full open source MySQL wire compliant database.  It uses the MySQL server as a frontend and the backend has been changed out and optimized for columnar storage.  MyISAM and InnoDB tables are supported also, alongside the InfiniDB columnar tables.  There is no limitations on the open source version and the enterprise support version.  Use as many nodes and TB as you desire.  If you are using MySQL now, you can drop in replace InfiniDB and should be able to connect through existing MySQL interfaces.  Do recommend using the packaged cpimport utility of InfiniDB for loading data into the tables, it has been optimized for insertion into InfiniDB engine and is recommended to use instead of LOAD DATA.

btw, I am an architect for InfiniDB, so here is my bias, free to try, use and scale :)

Here is the example PHP from php.net running against my InfiniDB instance locally:

I changed in my php.ini to point to the mysql.sock in the InfiniDB install (I am running the PHP on the same server as the DB)

```
; Default socket name for local MySQL connects.  If empty, uses the built-in
; MySQL defaults.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-socket
mysql.default_socket = /usr/local/Calpont/mysql/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Using this phptest.php (basically the copy from php.net with my own db and tables)

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_select_db('wide') or die('Could not select database');

// Performing SQL query
$query = 'SELECT count(*) FROM wide';
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    foreach ($line as $col_value) {
        echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
    }
    echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Then running:

```
[root@michael-vm2 tmp]# php phptest.php 
Connected successfully<table>
    <tr>
        <td>100000</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is all off a stock install of InfiniDB.  Just change your create statement to specify the engine=infinidb and you are good to go.

http://infinidb.co/

Comment: but mysql_* functions have already been deprecated, could you update your examples to use mysqli_* or PDO instead? btw, been looking onto infiniDB too, seems promising. thanks! P.S. yeah the OP is looking for MySQL specific stuff, but at least mention or add a side note so that other users reading this would know too.. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Ok got an answer for you .
I am a big fan of `HP Vertica database`, so i would recommend you use `HP Vertica database` if you want to make use of blazing speed.

- [Here is an article i have wrote on how to connect to `Vertica` using
  `PHP`](http://aodba.com/main_articles_single.php?art=12&page=vertica)
- [Here another article on how to create an ODBC Vertica](http://aodba.com/main_articles_single.php?art=13&page=vertica)
- [Here is how you can install Vertica Database](http://aodba.com/main_articles_single.php?art=83&page=vertica)e

Vertica is a Columnar Database that make full use of MPP,[Data Compression](http://aodba.com/tut_output_mysql.php?tut=6&page=vertica), inline Clustering.
 Is easy to install and maintain.
 *Fell free to bother me with Vertica related questions*

I suggest you install the CE(comunity edition) and test it , is easy to install and it's operation system are a joke ! kkk i mean it's nood type of database , it act on it's own.

Comment: thx for very nice answer and also need to know differences between Community Edition vs Paid Edition?

Comment: community edition has a limit of 1 tb with 3 max nodes per cluster and Paid/Enterprise edition comes with no nodes limitation and its features are richer !

Comment: woooooooooow only one tb :O :O I have to search for new tool :(

Comment: how much data do you have ?

Comment: more than 50M rows and more than 10 tb

Comment: you have then stored in what database ? SQL SERVER !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49960/discussion-between-up-one-and-hassan-magdy)

Comment: i moved the discussion in the chat ! enter there

Comment: It might be that your data stored in Vertica will be using up 90% less space then your MySQL database.